# Using CFFile to write csv file to server for download. How to prevent data from being saved as HTML Encoded?

Tags: csv, coldfusion, cffile

Using CF9, I want to write output to a csv file for user download.

```
<cfinvoke component="RAMP.cfcData.reportMonthlyTotals" method="report" xport="1" returnvariable="rpt" />
<cfset columnList = "Project Number,Project Name,Organization,Division,Group" />

<cffile action="write" file="#xportPath#" charset="utf-8" output="#columnList#" />
<cfset csvRow = "" />
<cfloop array="#rpt.data#" index="row">
<cfset csvRow = arrayToList(row,",") />
<cffile action="append" file="#xportPath#" charset="utf-8" output="#csvRow#" />
</cfloop>
```

The output of the method report is an array of arrays.  The returnformat of the function is "JSON".  This same function returns data used in a JQuery DataTables grid.

```
rtn.data = [
["itemOne", "itemTwo", "itemThree"],
["itemOne", "itemTwo", "itemThree"],    
]
```

The problem I am having is that some of the data has special characters.  This is output from the same function to a textarea on a test page.

```
CC2014118463,"Employee Townhall with CSO Q3 - São Paulo","CMO Communications & Public Relations","CALA Comms"
```

The csv file has the same line as:

```
CC2014118463,"Employee Townhall with CSO Q3 - S&#227;o Paulo","CMO Communications & Public Relations","CALA Comms"
```

What is causing the special character in San to be coverted to &#227 ?
I have tried different charset settings when I write and append the file.
I have also tried changing return format of the cfc, in the event it was an json encoding issue.  But so far, no luck.

Thanks in advance for the assistance.
Gary

Comment: The data (`rpt.data`) is encoded and the textarea simply happens to decode it. You should probably avoid encoding `rpt.data` and instead use `htmlEditFormat()` for the textarea - assuming you have access to `RAMP.cfcData.reportMonthlyTotals`.

Comment: Thanks Alex, the encoded data was indeed legacy data stored in the database.  After cleaning up the data, the export is working as expected.